# How to delete ephemeral Slack message

Tags: c#, slack, slack-api

When a user uses a slash command, I post an ephemeral message to just that user. When they click a button I want that ephemeral message to either delete or update. Right now I'm just trying to get the delete part working.

In the Slack API documentation it says to send a HTTP POST to the response_url. The only response_url I get when a user clicks a button is something like this: https://hooks.slack.com/actions/XXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYYYYY/ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ

When I send a POST to that url, I get an error(I'm not sure what the error is, I just know that my code fails on a try/catch).

The JSON I'm sending to that URL looks like this:

```
        {
            "response_type" = "ephemeral",
            "replace_original" = "true",
            "delete_original" = "true",
            "text" = ""
        };
```

I see in the Slack API documentation it says I should be sending that JSON to a URL that begins with https://hooks.slack.com/services/ however I'm not receiving any response_url that has the /services/.

Here is the C# code I am using to send the response:

```
       var replaceMsg = new NameValueCollection();
       replaceMsg["delete_original"] = "true";
       replaceMsg["replace_original"] = "true";
       replaceMsg["response_type"] = "ephemeral";
       replaceMsg["text"] = "";                    
       var responseReplace = client.UploadValues(button.response_url, "POST", replaceMsg);
```

Edit: It looks like I'm getting a 404 error when I try to send that

```
Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

However, when I paste the exact URL into my browser I don't get a 404, I see a JSON.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Try inspecting headers of the successful and failed requests to see if there are differences (use browser network tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something very similar not too long ago and was able to get it working, though it was tricky.

This post helped me big time: [How to remove Ephemeral Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496747/how-to-remove-ephemeral-messages/47537170#47537170)

I would do two things:

1) make sure you know what that POST response failure is as it may contain useful information.

2) It looks like you're sending in the string `"true"` instead of the boolean values, I'm guessing you probably want to send the boolean values instead:

```
{
   "response_type" = "ephemeral",
   "replace_original" = true,
   "delete_original" = true,
   "text" = ""
};
```

Comment: Then this may be a C# issue, I'll update my main post with the code.

Comment: Possibly. What is the full response of that POST that you're saying errors out?

Comment: Looks like I'm getting a 404 error: "Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." Strange because when I paste the response_url into my browser I see a JSON, no 404.

Comment: That's helpful info. I would then look at the HTTP request you're making from your code and try to sort out why it is returning a 404 and not a 200 response code. You could be passing in the wrong URL, or maybe as @theMayer pointed out you might be missing a required HTTP Header.

Answer (score 0):

@theMayer and @Aaron were correct about the headers being wrong.

Setting the headers solved the issue, like so:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html");
var response = client.UploadData(button.response_url, "POST", Encoding.Default.GetBytes("{\"response_type\": \"ephemeral\",\"replace_original\": \"true\",\"delete_original\": \"true\",\"text\": \"\"}"));
```